# atmega32 interfacing taking user input from keypad

Tags: user-input, atmega, keypad

Hi I am a newborn person to this AVR coding world .

I am developing a 4*4 keypad to take user inputs and to display some of the things in the 16*2 LCD display.

So please u guys as experts I request your suggestions and explanations of such these points.

I kindly request your help on,

1. I can't understand the following code parts,

   ```
   #define D5 eS_PORTD5 -

   DDRD = 0xFF;
   DDRB = 0x0F;
   ```
2. is this code fragment is used a predefined function , if so what is that,

   ```
   if(bit_is_set (PINB,6))
   ```

the full code of this is attached herewith.

thank you for your kindness to waste your time on reading this , please help for a beginner if you know evenone of these things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DDRD = 0xFF sets all bits of register DDRB to 1 which is setting the port D as outputs

(1 = output, 0 = input)

DDRB = 0x0F is setting portb low 4 bits as output, upper 4 bits as outputs.

bit_is_set a #define from sfr_defs.h, in this case, it checks if bit 6 is set from the PINB port.

it is the equivalent of (PINB & (1<<6))

Comment: thank you for your comment #lostbard . can you please explain (define D5 eS_PORTD5) usage and I really need a small clarification that how to detect the user inputs from keypad,    really appreciate your help !!!

Comment: #define D5 eS_PORTD5 isnt doing much except saying that whenever you write D5, it will be really using eS_PORTD5.

Comment: on code I have seen before for lcd.h,  (https://electrosome.com/interfacing-lcd-atmega32-microcontroller-atmel-studio/)  they use that #define to then detemine what port / bit to use in the lcd code - ie: D5 = 35, then in the code, if D5= 35, change bit X in port Y.